# Rails class method isn't setting attribute, though it shows in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods

I have a method which assigns an Item's price. The method calculates the price correctly and shows that price in the view, but when in the console it remains nil. How come setting the price doesn't save?

edit: price is a big decimal, if it makes a difference.

```
def calc_price
  self.price = 0
  newprice = 0
  pr = 0

  pr = if amount < 10
    product.pricerange0
  elsif amount < 25 
    product.pricerange1
  elsif amount < 50 
    product.pricerange2
  elsif amount < 100
    product.pricerange3
  elsif amount < 250
    product.pricerange4
  elsif amount < 500
    product.pricerange5
  end

  inkprice = (self.inkcolors*1.50)
  newprice = ((pr+inkprice)*self.amount)
  self.price = newprice
  return self.price
end
```

After running the method in the console it assigns the price correctly, but it doesn't get assigned from the view.

Comment: Unrelated, but couldn't you just do `pr = if amount < 10; 0; elsif amount < 25; product.pricerange1; elsif amount < 50; product.pricerange2...` etc? It's just kind of difficult to read as-is, at least for me. Using the return value of the `if` statement eliminates one chunk of repetition, just checking the upper bound removes another.

Comment: @davenewton I changed it, thanks! I figured there was a better way but hadn't learned of one yet.

Comment: I didn't mean to use the semicolons, SO just doesn't support newlines in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to call save after setting the value:

```
def calc_price
  self.price = 0
  newprice = 0
  pr = 0

  pr = if amount < 10; 0; elsif amount < 25; 
  product.pricerange1; elsif amount < 50; 
  product.pricerange2; elsif amount < 100;
  product.pricerange3; elsif amount < 250;
  product.pricerange4; elsif amount < 500;
  product.pricerange5; end

  inkprice = (self.inkcolors*1.50)
  newprice = ((pr+inkprice)*self.amount)
  self.price = newprice # this just sets the value in this object
  self.save             # this will persist the value in the database
  return self.price
end
```